# every time strstr() function is returning false. when i pass any input always function is returning false

Tags: c, strstr

I am trying to search is there any track available in tracks array. When I gave any input always `strstr()` function is returning false. If I use else block, every time else block is executing.

```
    char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima",
    };

    // function to search the track with entered search string //
    void find_track(char search_for[]) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            /** this if condition is returning false every time */
            if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for)){
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
            }/**else{
                printf("some thing went wrong @ %i\n", i);
            }**/
        }
    }



    int main() {
        char search_for[80];
        printf("Search for: ");
        fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
        find_track(search_for);
        return 0;
    }
```

Input:

```
gcc test.c -o test && test
```

Search for : `with`

expected result : `Track 2:'Dancing with a Dork'`

please help me.

Comment: single step with your debugger.

Comment: [Removing the newline from fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets` reads the newline character as well. You need to remove it from `search_for` before passing it to `find_track`.

See [Removing the newline from fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776).

Comment: Go with the elegant bonus answer, not the ugly accepted answer

Comment: I see multiple ways to achieve this, but what is the difference between "search_for[len-1] = '\0;" and "search_for[strcspn(search_for,"\n")] = 0;". And which is better to use and why?

Comment: @Nara, I think `search_for[strcspn(search_for,"\n")] = 0;` is better since it makes no assumptions about where the newline character is found.